# getResources().getIdentifier возвращает 0

Tags: java, android

Подскажите почему getResources().getIdentifier всегда возращает ноль? R.drawable.service_logo50 существует в  R.java, имеет свой идентификатор (public static final int service_logo50=0x7f02007e), даже если я указываю другой ресурс, то все равно picId = 0. В чем может проблема?

```
int picId = getResources().getIdentifier("R.drawable.service_logo50", "drawable", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

надо так:

```
int picId = getResources().getIdentifier("service_logo50", "drawable", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
```

Comment: Точно! Все гениальное - просто=)